# Why doesn't my 10-bit monitor use 10-bit?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate, color-depth

I build my computer in 2014 with a Z87-Pro, GTX 780 and a Dell U2713HM and I've been using that until now. I just bought a new monitor, the Asus PA329C which is a 10-bit monitor and now use that as my primary monitor with the U2713HM as a secondary.

My issue is that I don't seem to get the 10-bit output on the PA329C. When I look at both Windows 10 Screen settings and the NVIDIA control panel it only shows 8-bit (without the option to select 10-bit).

I'm also curious about the refresh rate as I can only select 60 Hz even though it seems to me it should be able to output up to 76 Hz.

I've tried different cables, both 3 different HDMI cables (two older I had lying around and the one that came with the monitor) as well as one DP cable. I've also tried swapping the GPU to an RTX 2060 I had in another machine but so far nothing has worked.

What am I missing and how do I use the full potential of my monitor?

Comment: @Tetsujin Could you clarify what is DP1.2 and HDMI 2.0a? The 2060 at least has HDMI 2.0b and DP 1.4.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry for not being clear. I meant, what do you suggest only have DP 1.2 and HDMI 2.0a. I know what they are.

Comment: @Tetsujin OK, though as I mentioned in my question I swapped to a 2060 (will edit the question to add RTX before 2060).

Comment: I missed that - way too far down the question.

Comment: Did you install the monitor driver in Windows? You need that to make Windows 10 understand the full capabilities of the monitor. Without it you will only get 8-bit and a limited range of standard VESA resolutions/refresh rates. And that driver is hard to get. The monitor section of the Asus web-site seems to have a lot of broken links.

Comment: Nvidia control panel->Display->Change resolution->point 3 chose second option here is setting to chose 8bit/10bit

Comment: @Silbee That may not be available if Windows isn't aware that the monitor is capable.

Comment: I don’t have a HDR monitor. But I guess whatever setting you’re looking for will not be labeled “10 bit” or the like but rather just “HDR” or “Windows HD Color”. // You can enable Adaptive Sync in the OSD.

Comment: Does your monitor have an HDR setting in its OSD that needs to be enabled before it will report 10-bit support to your OS? I've plugged in a 144Hz HDR monitor (via DP) and immediately gotten "HD Colour" settings in the Windows Display Settings area as well as switchable 8/10 bit in the nvidia Control Panel resolution page.

Comment: @Tonny That might be it, honestly didn't think of drivers for the monitor. In device manager it shows up as a Generic PnP-display (own translation from local language setting). I'll make an update once Asus Support site it up again.

Comment: @Silbee Tried that (see question).

Comment: @DanielB Yes, the monitor supports HDR 600 but I'm looking for color depth, and yes that setting exists as others point out (Nvidia control panel). Status also shows in Wintodws display settings. Will look into HDR when I get the color depth working though.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, it has an HDR setting in the OSD. It is greyed out though so I can't change it. Any idea why that might be? I've now successfully managed to install the drivers for the monitor.

Comment: I know my monitor (or at least my graphics card) only works with HDR over DisplayPort. On HDMI I get only 8bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers are in the comments really (thanks Mokubai and Tonny) but here's a summary:

1. Install drivers for display (not sure if this did anything as I had to do #2 as well, which I did after this).
2. Connect monitor using DisplayPort. HDMI didn't work. My PC doesn't have video over USB-C so haven't tried it.

I couldn't find any documentation on this regarding my monitor but in the end I had to use DisplayPort to use the monitors full potential. HDMI 2.0b, which my monitor and GPU has, supports 10-bit and HDR as far as I know but it didn't work for me with my GPU and monitor combination.

The reason I used HDMI instead of DisplayPort in the beginning was that my secondary monitor only supports full resolution using DisplayPort and DVI-D, and DisplayPort is a nicer cable. I was lucky that my new GPU that was needed for DisplayPort 1.4 also has a DVI-D output so I can use full potential of both my monitors.

Setting up a multiple monitor solution was more tricky than I imagined.